# jQuery.isArray is true, but split() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript:

```
console.log($.isArray(thisValue)); //true
strDisplay = thisValue.split(" "); //TypeError: thisValue.split is not a function
```

'thisValue' is a property of an object I'm getting from a .json file. In certain cases, my object's properties could be an array. I look at the raw .json file, and it seems to be properly formatted as an array.

Any ideas on what could be going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you thinking about "slice()" maybe?

Comment: you probably want `join`

Comment: Well, `strDisplay` would suggest he wanted `Array.join()`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Split array elements apart into smaller units, or join them together with a white-space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.split()` is a method to be used on `String`s, not `Array`s.

[Reference and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

It appears that you want [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), which glues together an `Array` into a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Split is for strings.
I would split a string into an array but not vice verse.

```
var x = "This is a string";
var arr1 = x.split(" ");

arr1[0] == "This"
arr1[1] == "is"
```

and so on